# Removing a className using ReactJS useState

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, use-state

The title pretty much sums it up. I want to remove a className from an element once a button is pressed, and for this, I have tried using `useState` hooks, a regular function and I'm using `onClick` on the button to call this function/setUseState, but the className list is still the same. Here is a sample of my code:

```
    function TileBoard() {
    
        const [openTileVisible, setOpenTileVisible] = useState(true);
        const [shuffler, setShuffler] = useState(0);
        const yellowTileIds = [9, 10, 11, 12, 15, 23, 24, 25, 33, 36, 37, 38, 39];
    
        let initialTiles = [];
    
        for (let i = 0; i <= 48; i++) {
            if (i === 48) {
                initialTiles.push(<Tile key={i} number={i} id={'openTile'} className={openTileVisible ? 'tile-black tile' : 'tile'}/>);
            } else {
                if (yellowTileIds.includes(i)) {
                    initialTiles.push(<Tile key={i} number={i} className={'tile-yellow tile'}/>);
                } else {
                    initialTiles.push(<Tile key={i} number={i} className={'tile-black tile'}/>);
                }
            }
        }
    
        const [tiles, setTiles] = useState(initialTiles);

    return (
      <div className={'game'}>
          <div key={shuffler} className={'board'}>
              <div className={'tiles'}>
                  {tiles}
              </div>
          </div>
          <button onClick={() => {
               setOpenTileVisible(false);
               shuffleArray();
          }}>SHUFFLE</button>
      </div>
    );
}
```

For some reason, this does not remove the class, even though the useState gets changed. Have I done something wrong with the className attribute when I create the object?

Here is shuffle method:

```
function shuffleArray() {
        let array = tiles;
        for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
            const temp = array[i];
            array[i] = array[j];
            array[j] = temp;
        }
        console.log(array);

        setTiles(array);
        // Using this to force the Rerender, since React doesn't count
        // change in element order in array as a reason to rerender.
        setShuffler(shuffler + 1);
    }
```

Comment: Don't use state for the tiles. Just render them

Comment: @evolutionxbox I used state so that shuffling the array would be easier. How do you propose I should do it instead? :)

Comment: Which class do you want to remove? I see 3 classNames...

Comment: @Undo I'm trying to remove the tile-black class from the Tile element with id='openTile'

Comment: The initializer value in `useState(initialTiles)` only sets the state the very first time and is ignored in subsequent renders.

Comment: @Martin but thats not even the state I'm using to remove the class. I found a way to bypass that when shuffling, but does that state really matter when thats not the one I'm using for this problem?

Comment: The right approach to such a feature is to shuffle the IDs and render fresh instead of shuffling an array of stale jsx elements.

Answer (score 0):

Make `tiles` the computed (and memoized) value of `useMemo` instead of using it as state, this updates the value when the dependencies change.

```js
import React, { useMemo } from "react";
```

```js
const tiles = useMemo(() => {
  const tiles = [];

  for (let i = 0; i <= 48; i++) {
    if (i === 48) {
      tiles.push(
        <Tile
          key={i}
          number={i}
          id={"openTile"}
          className={openTileVisible ? "tile-black tile" : "tile"}
        />
      );
    } else {
      if (tiles.includes(i)) {
        tiles.push(
          <Tile key={i} number={i} className={"tile-yellow tile"} />
        );
      } else {
        tiles.push(<Tile key={i} number={i} className={"tile-black tile"} />);
      }
    }
  }
  return tiles;
}, [openTileVisible, shuffler]);
```

Comment: I included the shuffle method in the post now. The way you showed, would probably work. But after deleting the useState with [tiles, setTiles] the shuffle method doesn't work properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
let array = tiles;
```

With this assignment, `array` is always referred to as the same `tiles` array which does go against [the immutability rule in React](https://danburzo.github.io/react-recipes/recipes/immutability.html).

Along with it, I'd suggest you use `React.cloneElement()` to clone your tile components that help to force re-rendering your tiles too.

You should modify it like below

```
function shuffleArray() {
        let array = [...tiles]; //assign a new tiles' array
        for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
            const temp = array[i];
            array[i] = React.cloneElement(array[j]); //clone your tile
            array[j] = React.cloneElement(temp); //clone your tile
        }
        console.log(array);

        setTiles(array);
        //setShuffler(shuffler + 1); //you don't need to use it anymore because the array modification has been forcing the re-rendering
    }
```

Comment: Yeah I probably should. Unfortunately the whole shuffeArray method wont work after refactoring according to the other answer. Since then I delete the useState with setTiles and replace it with the const tiles he suggested. And the changing of class worked, but then the shuffling doesnt work anymore. I'm very new to React so sorry for all the questions.

Comment: No worries, we're here to help. The main reason is that you want to shuffle yellow tiles, right? @PMolnes

Comment: I want to shuffle all the tiles randomly, and make one invisible. To create a Tile Puzzle game. I got the shuffling to work with the code I posted, but not removing the className of the tile with id=openTile that makes it black. @Nick Vu

Comment: how about yellow tiles? @PMolnes

Comment: Those should also be shuffled around randomly. @Nick Vu